# Do decorations on glasses absorb?

Tags: kashrut-kosher, sephardi-mizrachi-eastern, meat-and-milk, glass

We are Sephardic and follow the opinion that glasses can be used for both meat and milk, whether hot or cold, because glass never absorbs.

According to this opinion, are glasses with decorations on them which aren't made of glass still may be used for both meat and milk?

e.g glasses with bronze parts and non-glass decorations:

[image]

Comment: First of all, consider editing your question to fit with the guidelines, this seems like a good question that can generate positive responses. Second of all, the difference between sefardi and ashkenaz is regarding kashering glass. Using glass for both meat and milk (obviously not cooking in the glass as a kli rishon) was and is allowed by ashkenazim. It happens to be a few decades ago it became popular to not use glass for both.

Comment: Most Ashkenazim do not use glass for both meat meat and hot milk, whereas us Sephardim do. For example, I will have hot tea in my glass with milk, and then later use it at a meat meal (after cleaning it). Also, I might bake chicken in a glass, then wash it, then bake eggplant Parmesan. Ashkenazim do not do this (according to what I know of them).